# PostgreSQL insert error into log_table

Tags: postgresql, error-handling

How can I insert an error message into a table in PostgreSQL 9.3
e.g

```
ERROR:  column "category_id" is of type smallint but expression is of type text
LINE 2: insert into "MOP" values($2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7);
```

Comment: Why do you think you can put a character value into an integer column? And you **have** to supply us with the table definition and the statement that caused the error.

Comment: i'm interested in the error. de query is just an example.

Comment: The error couldn't be clearer: you can ***NOT*** insert character data into a numeric (here: smallint) column. It's pretty obvious if you read the error message.

Comment: Maybe I should have be more clear when i run my 20 or 25 functions (stored procedure) i want to save the start,End of the functions and the Errors in my log table.

Comment: Start with [Trapping Errors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) in plpgsql documentation.

Comment: Happy New Year all, what i found in the documentations is  RAISE statement en not how to get the error in my log table? is that possible?